# Successive "approximately equal" signs

Tags: notation

Which is notation is stylistically preferred?

> $$\Delta U = mg \frac{R^2h}{R^2 + R h} \approx mg \frac{R^2 h}{R^2} = mgh$$

or

> $$\Delta U = mg \frac{R^2h}{R^2 + R h} \approx mg \frac{R^2 h}{R^2} \approx mgh$$

And does the rule change if you are using line breaks?

Logically, it seems like the second notation implies that you are making *an additional* approximation, so I am inclined to say that the first notation is correct.

But if a reader is just skimming the formulas without looking at the derivation, they might mistakenly think that an approximation is being used at all.

I am trying to find an example, but it seems like most of the books I can find have simply dodged the issue by adding a discussion in between the formulas. Perhaps there is a style guide somewhere that advises what to do in situations like this.

Comment: The first one is correct, provided $R\not=0$.

Comment: I think „we find $\Delta U \approx mgh$ since [first version]“ is an option. Or just use an align to make the $\approx$ more prominent.

Comment: They're both correct, since (strictly speaking) $a \approx b$ includes $a = b,$ so you probably want to ask which is more precisely correct (or some such wording). I would use the first one, as it conveys more information; indeed, it does so without any increase in words or symbolic clutter. If the approximation $\Delta U \approx mgh$ is very important in what follows, you could preface this with something like "For later use we note that $\Delta U \approx mgh,$ which follows from ..."

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct, in exactly the same way that you would write e.g.
$$e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}\geq1+\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{x}{x-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

> Logically, it seems like the second notation implies that you are
>   making an additional approximation, so I am inclined to say that the
>   first notation is correct.

I agree with this reasoning.

> But if a reader is just skimming the formulas without looking at the
>   derivation, they might mistakenly think that an approximation is being
>   used at all.

If you are worried about this, you might add an extra line containing
$$
\implies \Delta U \approx mgh
$$
or the like.